# Why quicksort test time result seems O(n)?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I want to test time cost with python for quicksort..
But it seems always O(n), it should be O(nlogn)..
This is my code

```
def quicksort(arr, left, right):
    if left >=right:
        return 
    random_index = random.randint(left, right)
    arr[left], arr[random_index] = arr[random_index], arr[left]
    pivot = arr[left]
    lt = left
    gt = right + 1
    i = left + 1
    while i < gt:
        if arr[i] < pivot:
            arr[i], arr[lt+1] = arr[lt+1], arr[i]
            lt += 1
            i += 1
        elif arr[i] > pivot:
            arr[i], arr[gt-1] = arr[gt-1], arr[i]
            gt -= 1
        else:
            i += 1
    arr[left], arr[lt] = arr[lt], arr[left]
    quicksort(arr, left, lt-1)
    quicksort(arr, gt, right)


if __name__=='__main__':

    s = 100000
    arr = list(range(0, s))
    random.shuffle(arr)
    start = time.time()
    quicksort(arr, 0, s-1)
    end = time.time()
    print(str(s) + "  ----  " + str(end - start))

    s = 800000
    arr = list(range(0, s))
    random.shuffle(arr)
    start = time.time()
    quicksort(arr, 0, s-1)
    end = time.time()
    print(str(s) + "  ----  " + str(end - start))

    s = 2000000
    arr = list(range(0, s))
    random.shuffle(arr)
    start = time.time()
    quicksort(arr, 0, s-1)
    end = time.time()
    print(str(s) + "  ----  " + str(end - start))
```

This is result

[image]

And I test many cases, and try many input sizes, but always O(n)...
I want to know why?

Comment: why do you think it's O(n)?

Comment: Putting the many other issues aside for a moment, it's important to remember that Big O notation is a **theoretical** property/metric of algorithms. A high-level example like this one is so far removed from that theoretical nature that I don't think we can make any conclusive statements from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do not have linear scaling. Your scaling is close to n log(n):

```
X  =np.array([10000, 100000, 800000, 2000000])
Y = np.array([0.0779, 1.11299, 9.99, 27.679])
Y / (X * np.log(X))
#array([8.458e-07, 9.667e-07, 9.187e-07, 9.539e-07])
```

Second, physical running time should not be used as a measure of computational complexity. It depends not only on the number of operations, but also on the system load and CPU scheduling.

Third, in reality, QuickSort does not guarantee O(n log(n)). In the worst case, when you start with a sorted or almost-sorted array, QS's performance is O(n^2).